# React: Setting state with array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

**Mission:**

*This section is to illustrate fully what I'm trying to do, and the code I'm working with.*

I'm trying to set the state of a `SearchContainer` component using an ajax call. The data that gets returned looks something like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":903,
      "name":"Adrian College",
      "url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrian_College",
      "nickname":"Bulldogs",
      "city":"Adrian",
      "state":"Michigan",
      "conference":"Michigan Intercollegiate Athletic Association",
      "athletics_url":null,
      "enrollment":20000,
      "selectivity":"High",
      "slug":null,
      "college_sports":[  
         {  
            "sport":{  
               "id":71,
               "name":"Softball",
               "gender":"Female",
               "division":"Division III"
            }
         },
         {  
            "sport":{  
               "id":68,
               "name":"Volleyball",
               "gender":"Female",
               "division":"Division III"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I'm getting this information with the following ajax (within the `SearchContainer` component), which I then try to set the state of `filteredColleges` with the data returned (referenced above):

```
$.ajax({
    url: `/api/search/colleges.json/?query=${query}`,
    method: 'GET',
    success: (data) => {
        this.setState({ filteredColleges: data });
    }
});
```

I'll be updating my `SearchResults` component like so:

```
<SearchResults filteredColleges={ this.state.filteredColleges }/>
```

Within `SearchResults`, I render the following:

```
const colleges = this.props.filteredColleges.map( function(college) {
    return <College college={college} key={college.id}/>
});
```

And within each `College` component, I want to be able to reference the list of sports that belong to that college.

**My Problem:**

When I try to set the state of `filteredColleges` within my `SearchContainer` component...

```
this.setState({ filteredColleges: data });
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {sport}).
```

I've tried parsing the data many different ways, but no luck. I'm pretty sure this means that I can't have the `sport` objects within my `data` array? Am I interpreting this error correctly? Is there any way to get around this?

***Edit #1: Sharing my College component***

```
import React from 'react';

export default class College extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { name, nickname, conference, url, enrollment, selectivity, city, state } = this.props;

        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{ this.props.college.name }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.college.nickname }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.college.conference }</td>
                <td><a href={ this.props.college.url } target="blank">{this.props.college.url}</a></td>
                <td>{ this.props.college.enrollment }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.college.selectivity }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.college.city }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.college.state }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.college.college_sports }</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the `College` component code with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `College` component is outputting objects from the `college_sports` array directly, something like:

```js
const college_sports = this.state.college.college_sports
<ul>
  { college_sports.map(sport=> <li>{sport}</li>) }
</ul>
```

But you can't output whole objects, like the error says. Try something like:

```js
const college_sports = this.state.college.college_sports
<ul>
  { college_sports.map(sport=> <li>{sport.name}</li>) }
</ul>
```

Comment: I haven't yet written the part that extracts college_sports. It's erroring out at `this.setState({ filteredColleges: data });`, right after my ajax call. I've tried logging `this.state.filteredColleges` after that line, and get nothing.

Comment: Ah, now that I can see the component, it's probably this line: `<td>{ this.props.college.college_sports }</td>`.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that you have multiple objects with the same name in an array. You could change your api to give you an array with no object names or unique object names for this section.

Comment: Which objects are you referring to that have the same name? I have a college_sports array within each college object, and each of those college_sports arrays has multiple sport objects. They're just arrays of objects within an array of objects.

Comment: Each object in 'college_sport' is named 'sport'